# How to get the name of a variable or object node passed by parameter in a delphi function?

Tags: delphi, function, variables, parameter-passing, delphi-2006

In Java we have something like `VarName.toString` to indetify the name of the var.

I have a code in Delphi and I need to achieve the same thing, because I have a `record` type that has many sub-strings that I need to identify:

```
type
THierarchyAccess = String; // receive the user permissions from the MySQL DB
THierarchy = record
      MOD_HIERARQUIA   : THierarchyAccess; // 'BROWSE_ONLY', 'MANAGE', 'NONE'...
      MOD_OPERADORES   : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_ESTATISTICAS : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_AUDITORIA    : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_HOMEPAGE     : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_HOTSITES     : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_MATRIZ       : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_NOTICIAS     : THierarchyAccess;
      MOD_VISITANTES   : THierarchyAccess;
          ...
          end;
...

function  TAccess.IsAccessPermited(apNeed, apHave: String): Boolean;
begin
// HERE I need to know not only the content of "apHave", 
// but if it came from THierarchy.MOD_HOTSITES or THierarchy.MOD_MATRIZ etc.
end;

...

if IsAccessPermited('BROWSE_ONLY', MyHierarchy.MOD_HOTSITES) then Form2.Open;
```

Is there an elegant way to identify what was the variable name passed to the function?

Comment: Nope. What's wrong with `if MyHierarchy.MOD_HOTSITES = 'BROWSE_ONLY'  then`?

Comment: If I get no permission information, I send an email to myself (support) telling that MyHierarchy.??? from the user XXXX is incomplete.

Comment: You could send the e-mail when you load the permission data from the database instead of when you're checking what you have. Then you have the database field name and can use that instead of trying to get the record field name.

Comment: There is no such toString method in Java. [Object#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returns a string representation of the object, not the name of a variable which holds the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi is not Java!

You will need to use completely different, strongly typed techniques. For example your code can be something like:

```
type
  THierarchyAccess = set of (haBrowseOnly, haManage, haNone {...});
  THierarchyMod = (hmHierarquia, hmOperadores, hmEstatisticas {...});
  THierarchy = array [THierarchyMod] of THierarchyAccess;
//...

function  TAccess.IsAccessPermited(apNeed: THierarchyAccess; apHave: THierarchy; hMod: THierarchyMod): Boolean;
begin
  case hMod of
    hmHierarquia:
      if apNeed <= apHave[hmHierarquia] then
        Beep;
    hmOperadores:
      if (apNeed + [haBrowseOnly]) <= apHave[hmOperadores] then
        Beep;
  end
end;

if IsAccessPermited([haBrowseOnly], MyHierarchy, hmOperadores) then Form2.Open;
```

Comment: I didn't know that we could use a type inside of the array[] definition. I don't know many things indeed, I am autodidata because there is no Delphi professional colleges at Amazônia... :-/

Comment: Any enumerated type can be used as index. For example Boolean or Byte.

Comment: And there are lots of Delphi professionals online. Some of them are writing official documentation at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com others write in personal blogs (http://www.delphifeeds.com), etc.

Answer (score 7):

In general, symbol names such as record field names or parameter variable names are not included in the executable image by native code compilers such as Delphi because native machine instructions only care about offsets and addresses, not names. This is one of the reasons why Delphi produced exes can be hundreds of times smaller than their equivalent .NET or Java apps.

However, type metadata such as field names can be useful for "self-sufficient" object streaming. This type metadata is usually called Run Time Type Information (RTTI) by native code compilers.

You can try compiling your types above with `{$M+}` enabled around the type declaration. Be sure to set `{$M-}` immediately afterwards to avoid bloating your exe with unneeded type names.

You will then need to use Delphi RTTI methods to access the names of the fields of the record structure.

However, I don't think this will work with your sample code, since you are passing the record field as a parameter to another function. To get the name of the nth field of a record, you need the record type.

Your `IsAccessPermitted()` function only receives the value of the contents of the record field. It has no idea what field was used to pass the value in, or even if a record was used at all

Answer (score 1):

As dthorpe (a former architect of Delphi!) says, that is impossible. But ISTM that your record could just as well be an array of THierarchyAccess.

I would do things this way:

```
type
  THierarchyMode = (mHierarchia, mOperadores, mEstatisticas, ... );

  THierarchy = array[THierarchyMode] of THierarchyAccess;

...

  procedure TAccess.IsAccessPermitted(const apNeed: THierarchyAccess; apHave: THierarchyMode; const Hierarchy: THierarchy);
  begin
    // access
    if apNeed = Hierarchy[apHave] then ...
```